# shiny example apps not running

Tags: r, shiny

I just installed shiny in RStudio and tried to run the example apps with runExample()
e.g. runExample("01_hello") but all I get as output is just the title, some input box and then the script code of the app.r, no plot though. In the console just a bunch of error messages:
Warning: Error in .Call: "_httpuv_decodeURIComponent" not available for .Call() for package "httpuv"
Stack trace (innermost first):
    1: runApp

Can you see the problem from the picture? 
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please provide example code so that we can help you decipher the problem.

Comment: Do you have `httpuv` installed?

Comment: @LauraS Thank you for trying to help. Here's what I did step by step: 1. open RStudio 2. install "shiny" with `install.packages("shiny")` 3. load "shiny" by: `library("shiny")` 4. run one of the example scripts e.g. `runExample("01_hello")` 5. the output is just the page title (Hello Shiny!), a label (Number of bins) and an edit field and further down all the code which is essentially  the r script for the example and is a part of the package (the problem should not be the code itself). I checked the `httpuv`, it's been installed with the `shiny`.

Comment: The printscreen of the actual output: ![Shiny example image not working](https://i.imgur.com/4csbKCl.png)

Answer (score 1):

Thank you, @hpesoj626 the `httpuv` package was installed in my R version, indeed, it just needed an update. So I resolved the problem by updating the `httpuv` package. On a side note, I'm just wondering why having clicked the option "Install dependencies" (RStudio -> Tools -> Install packages...) does not include the newest versions (updated packages) of dependencies needed for the actual package to run correctly? How am I as a user supposed to know what packages (dependencies) that e.g. shiny needs to run, need an update? Anyway, thank you both again for your interest.